# How essential is vitamin B3 to the diet?

Tags: vitamins, diet, biosynthesis

I know this might seem contradictory since by definition a vitamin is an essential part of the diet but I have read that **nicotinamide**, a form of vitamin B3, can be synthesised from **L-tryptophan**. Is it possible for a person to synthesise all their vitamin B3 requirements from one's dietary intake of L-tryptophan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [one study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15895512):

> It was calculated that if the excretory percentage of niacin metabolites in the urine were 60%, of the tryptophan ingested, the conversion factor would be a value of 67, meaning that is 67 mg of tryptophan is equal to 1 mg of niacin.

However, the study has a pretty low power with only 10 participants and an indirect measure of niacin.

Is it *possible* that a person could get all of their niacin from tryptophan? Probably - you just need to eat enough tryptophan, which is also [an Essential Amino Acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_amino_acid). The body may preferentially keep Tryptophan (which it does not store) until Niacin runs out (which also cannot be stored).